# How to define a generic inner class?

Tags: typescript

Defining inner classes in Typescript is pretty easy:

```
class A {
    static B = class B {
    }
}
```

We can even use type parameters for the class expressions:

```
class A<T> {
    static B = class B<T> {
    }
}
```

and have to add a namespace entry to be able to use `B` as a type:

```
namespace A {
    export type B = InstanceType<typeof A["B"]>;
}
```

However, this doesn't make `B` a generic class. When I use this class with a type parameter like:

```
protected buckets: Array<A.B<T>>;
```

I get the error ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGt6EAuYeAlsNAELQC80okMZSqmO0AvhhgJAAOATgPZ4ApsGEATaACMArsADWQvBAD8ALji9eYAJ7xYAOgYpkAbgzsMAOzABbIRG5hgQuOiw4hAD279eeaHja3C4U1ACSlvhgls6IQULwgcH8AGZwANoARGSZALqm5hxAA)):

> Type 'B' is not generic.(2315)

What is required to make B generic?

Comment: TS does not support higher kinded types

Comment: You can use [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions) as shown in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq11km). Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I know this approach as class expression, but as you can see I use that already in the code above. But I see now what was missing. I just have to add a type parameter to the type export in the namespace. That's all. Your new playground link shows it. So yes, post that as your answer.